# What is the minimum set of permissions when using Facebook login with omniauth?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, omniauth

I am using `omniauth-facebook` `1.4.1` with Ruby on Rails `3.2.8`

I want users to be able to authenticate using their Facebook account. All I need from them is their email address or first name.

How do I configure omniauth so that I get just the email or first name?

Specifying `'email'` as `:scope` comes back far more data than just email.

```
config.omniauth :facebook, "appid", "appkey", :strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook, :scope => 'email'
```

Answer (score 0):

Same here, but it's not possible as basic information includes the friend list.

From [official docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions):

> Reference
>   
>   Basic Info (Default)
>
> Basic info is part of every request for permissions.  It includes
>   several elements from a person's public profile **and a list of their
>   friends**.
>
> On the web, `basic_info` is implied with every request
>   and isn't required, although the best practice is to include it. 
>   Passing `basic_info` is **required on iOS and Android
>   with every permission request**.
>
> A person's public profile refers to the following properties on the
>   user object by default:
>
> - `id`
> - `name`
> - `first_name`
> - `last_name`
> - `link`
> - `username`
> - `gender`
> - `locale`
> - `age_range`
> - Other public information
>
> The friend list is the friend list node on
>   the user object.
>
> User permissionDescription
>
> `basic_info`
>
> Gives
>   access to a subset of a person's public profile and friend list. 
>   Required when requesting permissions on iOS and
>   Android.